# JTextArea stretches when setWrapLine

Tags: java, jtextarea

I have the following code: the problem is that when i run the application, the JPanel containing those components stretches because of setLineWrap(true) I've inserted the JTextArea in a JScrollPane as suggested here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html
but with no result

```
titolo=new JLabel("title");
    text=new JTextArea("");
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(text);


    text.setLineWrap(true);

griglia=new GridBagLayout();
gbc=new GridBagConstraints();
setLayout(griglia);

buildConstraints(gbc,0,0,1,1,100,1);
griglia.setConstraints(titolo,gbc);

buildConstraints(gbc,0,1,1,1,100,100);
griglia.setConstraints(scrollPane,gbc);

add(titolo);
    add(scrollPane);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [GridBagConstraint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#GridBagConstraints%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Insets,%20int,%20int%29) here in the **fill - The initial fill value** use **GridBagConstraints.NONE**.

Comment: Great :) Can you explain me the why? I really cant understand. The size of the panel that contains the jscrollpane is controlled by an upper-level layout manager; shouldnt the size already defined?

Comment: Oh that's bad, things are getting better but i still have a problem; The problem is that now the scrollPane (with the JTextArea inside it) doesnt fill completely it's available space, so i get empty space all around it. Any idea?